# I had an interview with a local hospital two weeks ago. Am i still in the running after receiving this email?

Tags: interviewing

Long story short: I graduated from University and applied for a job at a local hospital and received an email from HR wanting to set up a phone interview. I promptly responded to HR, but i never heard anything back. Two months pass i am still searching and I take a wild shot and email the HR contact seeing if the job is still active. Over the weekend I get an email from a Hiring Manager who said the job is still open and wanted me to come interview the following week. I went and interviewed and the interview went extremely well. She told me she did not know the exact timeline because she needed to meet with two more managers to give her assessment since the job consisted of covering extra shifts at two nearby hospitals if needed. I emailed the hiring manager after two weeks and she said they have a few more to interview and than they will make a final decision.Before i interviewed, the job was taken down from the website, but it still said active even though you can't apply to it anymore. I am still applying elsewhere, but it just seems it is taking them a long time to make a decision.

Comment: There is no way to know with out getting into the head of the person making the decision.  Assume you are but keep applying for other positions in case you are not selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Most likely they are still interviewing. Hospitals are fond of their bureaucracy, and the process may take a long time.

Comment: "I emailed the hiring manager after two weeks and she said they have a few more to interview" - This is the answer already. You interviewed two weeks ago, and now you followed up and got your answer (they are still deciding).

Comment: If you haven't been told so, you are not yet eliminated from the competition. The delay may be because there are final approvals to go through, or it may be that they are offering it to someone else but will consider you if that person doesn't accept. Or other things. I would write a full answer if this question was open.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that HR is totally incompetent and keep job searching. 3 months is ridiculous if they're not even giving you information and being vague.

Continue following up if you can't find another job and you might eventually get lucky, remember though that this same HR department will be organising your shifts and transport to other hospitals etc,.